# what is the difference between sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split and torch.utils.data.random_split?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, transformer-model

I am using **transformer** to do a speech classification task.

I used two methods to split **my_dataset** into training set and test set.

The first is torch.utils.data.random_split:

```
train_len = int(0.9 * len(my_dataset))

lengths = [train_len , len(my_dataset) - train_len]

train_set, valid_set = random_split(my_dataset, lengths)
```

The second is sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split:

```
train_set, valid_set = train_test_split(my_dataset, test_size=0.1)
```

I have tries many times. When I use the first method, the accuracy rate is always 60%, but when I use the second method, the accuracy rate is only 55%.

So what is the difference between sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split and torch.utils.data.random_split?

**The two methods are only different in the way the data set is divided, and the others are the same.**

Comment: Is it really always 60% and always 55%? Are you using seeds? If you use seeds you will always get the same result and due to randomness the results can vary. By chance one split can be better than another. If you do not use seeds this is strange. Try to implement it with k-fold cross validation.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a different split. There are many ways to spilt 90:10. If the dataset is not large enough, the accuracy will depend on the actual split. You could compare the entries of the splits.